# mediaNdk undefined reference to 'AMediaCodec_signalEndOfInputStream'

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediacodec

can not find `AMediaCodec_signalEndOfInputStream` on link process.

[ExportThread.cpp](https://gist.github.com/fantasyRqg/c8cfbdf3a21c22d6d324b2d14c1db1a7) source

[configure file](https://gist.github.com/fantasyRqg/7d430f6e5041a35bb7b54cd09734dd81)

apilevel `android-21`

here is my config

CmakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(${Lib_Name}

                       android
                       mediandk
                       EGL
                       GLESv3
                       log )
```

gradle.build

```
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
//            , 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21'
            }
        }
```

errors

```
[35/35] Linking CXX shared library /Users/rqg/ASProjects/PboTest/muses/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so
  FAILED: : && /Users/rqg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/Users/rqg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/rqg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem /Users/rqg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -Wall -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a --sysroot /Users/rqg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o /Users/rqg/ASProjects/PboTest/muses/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/DecodeThread.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/DelayThread.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/EffectLine.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/EffectManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/ExportThread.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/NativeSurfaceTexture.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/Painter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/PboPool.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/Player.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/PrepareThread.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/RenderManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/RenderTask.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/effect/BlurEffect.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/effect/BoostEffect.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/effect/ChaplinEffect.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/effect/Effect.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/effect/FadeEffect.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/effect/NormalEffect.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/framesource/IFrameSource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/framesource/ImageFrameSource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/framesource/VideoFrameSource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/gl/EglCore.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/gl/surface/EglSurfaceBase.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/gl/surface/OffscreenSurface.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/gl/surface/WindowSurface.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/render/BlurRender.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/render/FadeRender.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/render/NormalRender.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/render/PolygonOffsetRenderer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/render/Render.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/util/DelayLooper.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/util/Looper.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/util/common.cpp.o  -landroid -lmediandk -lEGL -lGLESv3 -llog -lm "/Users/rqg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a" && :
  /Users/rqg/ASProjects/PboTest/muses/src/main/cpp/ExportThread.cpp:37: error: undefined reference to 'AMediaCodec_signalEndOfInputStream'
  /Users/rqg/ASProjects/PboTest/muses/src/main/cpp/ExportThread.cpp:107: error: undefined reference to 'AMediaCodec_createInputSurface'
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: post `ExportThread.cpp` then

Comment: @pskink add my `ExportThread.cpp` used on `line 37`

Comment: seems that `libmediandk.so` misses those symbols, go to `lib` folder and try to run `nm libmediandk.so | grep AMediaCodec_signalEndOfInputStream`

Comment: there is no `AMediaCodec_signalEndOfInputStream ` ,  is there and workaround to do this work ?

Comment: ok what you see if you grep for `AMediaCodec_` ? do you see 18 symbols?

Comment: there has 17 symbols. but I find `AMediaCodec_signalEndOfInputStream ` in `android-26`'s `libmediandk.so` . but in header file this method is marked available above `android-21`

Comment: no, i searched 21, 22, 23 and 24 and no header had `AMediaCodec_signalEndOfInputStream` - according to you it should be in `NdkMediaCodec.h` but it is not - so i have no idea how you were able to compile your code

Comment: header file in `Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/media/NdkMediaCodec.h` . In platforms `android-26`'s header also not contain `AMediaCodec_signalEndOfInputStream `,but symbols can found in its lib file

Comment: your command has two `--sysroot=` so there is something wrong here imho (one points to `/Users/rqg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm` the second to `/Users/rqg/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot`

Comment: yes, here is my config files https://gist.github.com/fantasyRqg/7d430f6e5041a35bb7b54cd09734dd81

Comment: `arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21' ` what if you change it to 26?

Comment: error msg `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot find "libGLESv3.so" from verneed[5] in DT_NEEDED list for "/data/app/rqg.fantasy.pbotest-2/lib/arm/libnative-lib.so"`

Comment: did you clean your build?

Comment: still get same error msg.    refresh gradle ,refresh c++ link project ,clean project , delete build dir and .externalNativeBuild dir.

Comment: so i dont know...

Comment: thanks you very much @pskink, I still can use java `MediaCodec` do some encode work. I just want keep all thing done in ndk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in NDK r.15. This API was only introduced in **android-26**. BTW, you can rely on Android Studio to set `-DANDROID_PLATFORM` to correspond to `minSdkVersion` as chosen in **build.gradle**.